# Why does partial replacement of 0 rows and 2 columns in a data.frame not work?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to write code where a certain data frame is partially replaced with fixed values. In some cases, it occurs that zero rows have to be replaced. This is illustrated in the code below: the data frame has a column `hit` which is entirely `FALSE`, and the values should be filled in for `hit==TRUE`.

I try to replace two columns at the same time. If I replace only one column at a time, the replacement function does nothing as expected if there are zero rows to be replaced.

However when I select a data.frame with 0 rows and 2 columns, and want to replace it with data from a matrix with 0 rows and 2 columns, I get an error that the replacement should be 8 elements long. (i.e. 4 rows / 2 columns). I don't understand why this would be the case? Sure I can program around it but I would like to understand...

```
df <- data.frame(hit=c(F,F,F,F), a=c(0,0,0,0), b=c(1,1,1,1))


df[df$hit==T,"a"] <- rep(1, length(which(df$hit==T)))
# this does nothing as expected

cbind(
  rep(1, length(which(df$hit==T))),
  rep(2, length(which(df$hit==T))))
# gives a matrix with 0 rows and 2 columns

df[df$hit==T,c("a", "b")] 
# gives a data.frame with 0 rows and 2 columns

df[df$hit==T,c("a", "b")] <- cbind(
  rep(1, length(which(df$hit==T))),
  rep(2, length(which(df$hit==T))))
# gives an error that my replacement should have 8 elements
```

Comment: `this does nothing as expected`  The `hit` column doesn't have any 'TRUE' values..

Comment: I'd have to do some digging to give a really technically accurate answer, but the basic mistake you're making here (which is fairly common for people learning R) is that you're assuming that matrices and data frames are more or less interchangeable, when in fact they are totally different data types that just happen to occasionally have the same "shape".

Comment: I do know how dataframes and matrices are different, but I don't understand why any other partial assignment of a matrix to a data frame works but this specific one doesn't...

Answer (score 1):

This will change the values of the **a** column of the **df** data frame if the **df$hit** is TRUE, the **a** value is changed to the **new_a_value**. The same for the **b**-value

```
df$a[which(df$hit == T)] <- new_a_value

df$b[which(df$hit == T)] <- new_b_value
```